# Dynamically add VSCode snippets from an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I was asking myself recently if it is possible to add snippets to either one of the workspace, language-specific or global json snippet files through a VSCode extension.

```
// something like
Command.addSnippet('''
{
"prefix": "my_snippt",
.... etc.
}
''')
```

Reading through the API documentation I did not find anything. If there is no way, how would you go about creating kind of a snippet manager?

Comment: you can write a completion provider and insert a snippet when you are requested (prefix match)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SnippetString`](https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/SnippetString.html) and a [CompletionItemProvider](https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/CompletionItemProvider.html) to dynamically suggest snippets.
Here is an [example](https://github.com/Sarrus1/sourcepawn-vscode/blob/master/client/src/Providers/spDocCompletions.ts).